# How to access the collection inside a class which inherits Collection<>?

Tags: c#, inheritance, collections, this, base-class

so I have a class:

```
    class TestCollection : Collection<Person> {

    }
```

and from main I add two Person objects to it. I wonder is there any way to access those two objects inside TestMethod without passing TestCollection tc? e.g.

```
    class TestCollection : Collection<Person> {
        public void TestMethod(TestCollection tc) {

        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried `this`?

Comment: Use `this`. For example: `this[index]`

Comment: You generally shouldn't inherit from collection types, unless you're actually adding logicto the collection type. Anyhow what exactly are you asking? You access them from within that class just as you would from the outside: `this.FirstOrDefault()`, `foreach (var item in this)`, and so on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you inherit something, the original isn't "inside" - it **is the same object**. So ultimately the answer is: `this`. If you need to bypass `virtual` methods that you've overridden, then: `base`.

In the case of `Collection<T>` *specifically*, there is also a `protected IList<T> Items {get;}` property that you can access from inheriting types - so you can bypass a *range* of abstractions by talking to `Items` instead of `this`.